# JQuery Can't Detect Result of PHP Echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

While working with JQuery and PHP, I encountered the following problem:

There is a DIV with a class of "Drag" which I use twice, once hard-coded in HTML, like this:

```
<div class='Drag'></div>
```

Subsquently, PHP generates this DIV within the same page, as follows:

```
echo "<div class='Drag'></div>";
```

The PHP code executes due to an AJAX call, so maybe this is the source of the problem?

As a result, the page contains these two DIVs. Also, there is jQuery code, as follows:

```
$(".Drag").draggable();
```

But, the jQuery code will only work for the DIV which was coded in HTML and not for the one which was generated by PHP.  Why?

Comment: Does the javascript come before the second div?

Comment: Post your code where you are generating div with php.

Comment: Share your code please, technicaly he shouldn't have a problem

Comment: Actually may be what you are saying, because the code comes after an AJAX call which is who calls the PHP script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `$(".Drag").draggable()` again after the ajax request is complete.

When you first call `$(".Drag").draggable()` the only div that is on the page is the one that is created in html.

Comment: Actually it is! But is there any way to only call the $(".Drag").draggable() once and then that it is used for everything?

Comment: @Weyooo not familiar with the draggable library but most likey not. One solution (may not be ideal), is to create an extra hidden .drag div, then instead of creating a .drag in the ajax put the contents of ajax call in the existing hidden .drag and in hide it. But that is more work than just calling .draggable() after ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Either your running the javascript before the DOM is finished loading and therefore before the second div is within context OR the jQuery library isn't setup to iterate over the selector.

The code to possibly resolve your issue

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.Drag').each(function() {
     $(this).draggable();
  });
});
```